# How we pass variable to c# method from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I want to pass variable to C# method from JavaScript is it possible ?

I had tried below code code:=

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var Query = window.location.search;
        var i = "<%=QueryStringModule.Decrypt(Query)%>"
    });
</script>
```

but i am getting the name "Query" doesn't exist in the current context

Please help me in the same

Comment: Read about ajax.

Comment: are you using asp.net mvc or webforms or what ?? what is your world??

Comment: Javascript runs on the client though (typically). Are you saying you want to run C# code when someone visits your webpage? If you want it run on the server side, you'll need to do an AJAX request.

Comment: Question is vague; where do you want to run the code? Browser? I'm asking because if you operate in node.js then it is possible.

Comment: @PowerStar He appears to be using ASP.NET based on `<% %>` which would imply it's server-side code.

Comment: @JBC  So then tell me it is mvc or web forms?  I know it is aspx. I am asking what is the front end

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. C# is code behind, so runs on the server. Any input is generated before the page is build on screen. So passing values from Javascript to C# is the other way around. Look into [`ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to send values to the server so they can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass JavaScript variables to the server side code in that way. JavaScript is client side, which means that the server side code has already run before JavaScript starts executing. To pass a variable back to the server, you will need to submit the variable to the server. You can use an AJAX request to do this without having to load the page again.